# require после fwrite

Tags: php, include, require

Всем привет!
Записываю в файл массив:

```
$fp = @fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/config.php", "w");
@fwrite ($fp, "<?php\n\$config_user = " . var_export($config, true) . ";\n?>");
@fclose ($fp);
```

Затем пытаюсь подключить:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/config.php";
```

Не выходит, выдает старые данные которые были до `fwrite`. 
На другом хостинге нет проблем, всё работает. Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Уберите `@` перед функциями и посмотрите, какую ошибку выдаст

Comment: ошибок не выдает, записывает в файл корректно

Comment: То есть с экранированием ошибок не работает, а без экранирования всё стало нормально?

Comment: нет в файл записывает и записывал корректно, но require читает старые данные, которые были до fwrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После строки

```
@fclose ($fp);
```

добавьте

```
if (function_exists('opcache_invalidate'))
    opcache_invalidate($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/config.php", true);
elseif (function_exists('apc_delete_file'))
    @apc_delete_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/config.php");
```

чтобы с APC и OPcache корректно обновление проходило. Хотя может у вас другой кэшер/акселератор стоит :)

Comment: спасибо, сработало. Может в настройках php что-то прописать чтобы было как у всех?

Comment: может есть какое то универсальное решение?

Comment: @15828, оформите класс/метод/функцию на входе в который/ую подаете нужный массив, имя файла, а он/она сохраняет файл и "борется" с кэшем. Больше наверное ни как, так как на разных машинах могут стоять разные кэшеры/акселераторы или не стоять вовсе. P.S. Или воспользуйтесь готовым классом (с github) для кэширования данных.